# Difference between DSL, DSLR, DRL in drools

Tags: eclipse, drools, dsl

Hi I am learning on the basics of Drools in java. Can anyone explain me about what is the difference between DSL, DSLR, DRL files that we write seperately with an example?

Comment: What's wrong with the relevant sections in the Drools Documentation manual that comes with the distribution?

Comment: I cannot answer your Q. Reason is that it isn't according to THE RULES. If I do, I'll be rebuked ("you should know better"), and the answer will be downvoted or even deleted by some Blockwart. Now I have downvoted your Q and voted to close it, so that, maybe, I get a pat on my head by s.o. like @StephenC.

Answer (score 4):

DRL is a declarative programming language. For example:

```
when
  Person (age > 18)
then ...
```

DSL mimics natural language. It gets converted to DRL. For example:

```
When a person is older than 18
then ...
```